# Fortran elemental functions vs elemental subroutines

Tags: multithreading, performance, fortran, parallel-processing, fortran90

Fortan allows elemental subroutines to have intent(inout) and intent(out) arguments, but elemental functions are only allowed intent(in).

Why is that? Is it just a stylistic convention, or is there something generically different about invoking functions and calling subroutines?

In other words,

```
Elemental Integer Function FOO(i)
  Integer, intent(in) :: i
    ...
  FOO=something
End Function
```

and

```
Elemental Subroutine FOO(i, v)
  Integer, intent(in)  :: i
  Integer, intent(out) :: v
    ...
  v=something
End Subroutine
```

— are these implementations of FOO equivalently efficient?

Comment: I can't figure it out, doesn't make much sense to call it a pure procedure if it has side effects. I would hazard a guess and say that the elemental function might be more efficient in the context of parallelisation, in that it is clear to the compiler how the procedure behaves.

Comment: I think that if a subroutine modifies only its own arguments and does not touch global variables, it is not difficult to compile such subroutine efficiently. It makes sense to have such functionality. For example, a random number generator should modify the state of the random number sequence (described by an array of integers) and return a random number. So it should have one intent(inout) and one intent(out) argument. Granted, the user may mess things up by passing shared variables to such subroutine. But then again, no programming paradigm is fool-proof.

Answer (score 7):

There is no point in having an elemental subroutine without at least one argument marked as `intent(out)` or `intent(inout)`, because you have to pass the result somehow. A function has its return value, a subroutine must use its arguments. In Fortran 2008 AFAIK elemental procedures doesn't have to be pure, but it's hard to imagine a useful elemental subroutine only through its side effects.